# Why "give me", not "give to me"?

Tags: prepositions

Why is "give me", and not "give to me" correct? As this is dative, and we are told that it is translated (from my language) with the preposition "to" in English.

Comment: Modern-day English does not have a dative case. "Give me the money" and "Give the money to me" are fine, but not *"Give to me the money"

Comment: @BillJ English does not have morphological dative but has semantic dative, governed by the preposition "to" (and morhologically is oblique case, distinct from nominative). Since the first phrase has no "to" proposition, the indirect object is not in Dative but morphologically it is still not nominative (it's "me", not "I").

Answer (score 2):

Here is the scoop on this in contemporary English. There are two possibilities, basically:

1) ***Give something* to *someone*** and :

**Give the book to John**.

Becomes:

**Give it to him**.

2) ***Give someone something***

**Give John the book**.

Becomes:

**Give him the book**.

So, basically these patterns show that: **give** is followed by a direct object and then to and the indirect object. Or **give** is followed by the indirect object, then the direct object.

It is useful to memorize and practice these forms/patterns.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a mistake to think that there will always be exact equivalents or one-to-one correspondences between English grammar and your native language's grammar.  It is also not always possible to give reasons: often the learner just has to learn that some verbs follow certain patterns.

As far as **give** is concerned, it is an example of a *ditransitive* (or *trivalent*) verb - it has both a direct object and an indirect object.

[UCL Grammar](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/function/ditr.htm) explains:

> Some verbs occur with two Objects:
>
> ```
>    We gave [John] [a present]
> ```
>
> Here, the [Noun Phrase] *a present* undergoes the "action" (a present is what is given). So *a present* is the Direct Object. We refer to the NP *John* as the INDIRECT OBJECT.
>
> Indirect Objects usually occur with a Direct Object, and they always come before the Direct Object. The typical pattern is:
>
> Subject -- Verb -- Indirect Object -- Direct Object

Further examples are then provided - in each case the verb is followed first by an indirect object and then a direct object (the same pattern that **give** typically follows):

> Tell  me  a story
>
> He showed     us  his war medals
>
> We bought     David   a birthday cake
>
> Can you lend  your colleague  a pen?

The grammar explains that

> Verbs which take an Indirect Object and a Direct Object are known as DITRANSITIVE verbs

and that sometimes they can double up as monotransitive verbs (e.g. "We bought a birthday cake").

As others have observed, **give** also allows an alternative pattern ("We gave a present to John").

Comment: Sure thing. A  more technical explanation though I find that at the level of this question, a less technical explanation was better. I guess I should have mentioned other verbs that work the same way. In any event, I didn't think my answer deserved downvotes....

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for your feedback.  I don't think your answer deserved downvotes either.  Sorry, I don't know why you got those.